# Botón Editar en tabla con DataTables

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Tengo el siguiente `.js` donde muestro en una tabla(dataTable) los datos de mi tabla sql. Para ello, quiero implementar en la última columna un botón Editar, que cuando lo pulse, me muestre mediante `js` un modal con sus datos, el cual pueda actualizar.

```
route_ppal = "/modelo/";

$(document).ready(function(){
    Cargar();   
});

function Cargar(){

var datatable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": route_ppal,
        "dataSrc": ""
        },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "marca" },
        { "data": "modelo" },
        { "data": "part_number" },
        { "data": "coste" },
        { "data": "caracteristicas" },
        {
            "data": null,
            "className": "button",
            "defaultContent": "<button value='id' OnClick='Mostrar(this);' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Editar</button>"
        }
    ]
});
}

function Eliminar(btn){
var route = route_ppal+btn.value+"";
var token = $("#token").val();

$.ajax({
    url: route,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    type: 'DELETE', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        Cargar();
        $("#msj-delete").fadeIn();
    }
});
}

function Mostrar(btn){
var route = route_ppal+btn.value+"/edit";

$.get(route, function(res){
    $("#id").val(res.id);
    $("#marca").val(res.marca);
    $("#modelo").val(res.modelo);
    $("#part_number").val(res.part_number);
    $("#coste").val(res.coste);
    $("#caracteristicas").val(res.caracteristicas);
});
}

$("#actualizar").click(function(){
var id = $("#id").val();
var marca = $("#marca").val();
var modelo = $("#modelo").val();
var part_number = $("#part_number").val();
var coste = $("#coste").val();
var caracteristicas = $("#caracteristicas").val();
var route = route_ppal+id+"";
var token = $("#token").val();

$.ajax({
    url: route,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {marca: marca, modelo: modelo, part_number: part_number, coste: coste, caracteristicas: caracteristicas},
    success: function(){
        Cargar();
        $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
        $("#msj-success").fadeIn();
    }
});
});
```

De la manera que lo tengo implementado, me muestra el botón, pero no los datos correspondientes a la fila seleccionada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea el botón de la siguiente manera, sin ninguna evento.

```html
"columns": [
    {"render": function () {
        return '<button type="button" id="ButtonEditar" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-warning botonEditar"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span></button>';
    }},
],
```

Deberia quedar asi:

```html
var datatable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": route_ppal,
        "dataSrc": ""
        },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "marca" },
        { "data": "modelo" },
        { "data": "part_number" },
        { "data": "coste" },
        { "data": "caracteristicas" },
        {"render": function () {
            return '<button type="button" id="ButtonEditar" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-warning botonEditar"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span></button>';
        }},
    ]
});
```

Llama la siguiente función, después de crear tu tabla:

```
editar("#mytable tbody",datatable);
```

Deberia quedar asi:

```html
var datatable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": route_ppal,
        "dataSrc": ""
        },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "marca" },
        { "data": "modelo" },
        { "data": "part_number" },
        { "data": "coste" },
        { "data": "caracteristicas" },
        {"render": function () {
            return '<button type="button" id="ButtonEditar" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-warning botonEditar"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span></button>';
        }},
    ]
});
editar("#mytable tbody",datatable);
```

La función que llamar sera esta:

```html
var editar = function(tbody, table){
  $(tbody).on("click","button.editar", function(){
    if(table.row(this).child.isShown()){
        var data = table.row(this).data();
    }else{
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
    }
    $('#editar_id').val(data[0]);
    $('#editar_nombres').val(data[1]);
    $('#editar_des').val(data[2]);

    $('#ModalEditar').modal('show');
    $("#editar_nombres").first().focus();
  })
}
```

El `if` que ves es una condición para saber si esta oculta la columna (el modo `responsive` de `datatables`), eso para que no te andes arrancando los pelos después como me paso a mi.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias, funciona. Ahora lo que no me funciona es cuando pulso el botón Actualizar de mi Modal. Me aparece el siguiente error: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:` , aunque lo tengo registrados en mis routes `Route::resource('modelo','ModeloController');` . Y una duda que tengo, ¿para qué sirve `$("#editar_nombres").first().focus()`?

Comment: Usas `laravel` al igual que yo. Ya edito tus etiquetas. Para modificar debes crear una ruta diferente como `modelo/editar` y cambia en el ajax y en la ruta que sea de tipo `post`. `first().focus()` es para cuando abras el modal se dirija el puntero al campo que indicas.

Comment: Para actualizar, lo he solucionado añadiendo el `$("#id").val()` en la función editar, luego ya la puedo utilizar con `$("#actualizar")`. Ahora me encuentro un problema al volver a cargar la tabla cuando se ha actualizado la fila. Me aparece el siguiente error `DataTables warning id=mytable --Cannot reinitialise DataTable. http://datatables.net/tn/3` Gracias.

Comment: ¿Como lo actualizas?

Comment: Como puedes ver en mi código con la función `Cargar()`

Comment: Para refrescar ejecuta esto: `$('#mytable').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Funciona todo perfecto!!

Comment: Ok, de nada. Siempre que vea tus preguntas de `laravel` y `dataTables` te ayudare. Sino lo veo me puedes escribir por el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/249134/pablo-contreras).